# Can't Call arrays in main method

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, methods

I'm practicing methods, but the problem is I want to separate inputting and sorting, the display method will be the main, I'm having trouble fixing this calling from other class.

This is my script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CaseProblem
{
    class Method
    {
        static void MethodInput()
        {
            int[] array = new int[5];
            int i;
            // loop for accepting values in array
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number:\t");
                array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        public static void MethodSort()
        {
            foreach (int i in array)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", i);
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(int[]array)
        {
            //sorting array value;
            Array.Sort(array); //use array's sort function

            Method.MethodSort(array);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What exaclty *is* your problem? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: Putitng `public` before `static void MethodInput()` might help.

Comment: adding parameters (such as the array) to the method might help, too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565824/c-sharp-sorting-numbers-with-methods

Comment: the name 'array' does not exist in the current context

line 37, void Method.MethodSort()
No overload for method 'MethodSort' Takes 1 arguments

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio is fully capable of telling you what's wrong by itself. Not much for us to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `Main()` ( or "EntryPoint" as we should call it ) cannot have `int[]`  as an input parameter but `string[]` instead you should learn basics of programming before starting to actually code something.

Second thing :

> I want to separate inputting and sorting

You can create an object called `Input`

```
public class Input
{
    public static void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static int? ReadInt(string reason)
    {
        Write(reason);
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int parsed = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(userInput, out parsed))
            return (int?)parsed;

        return null;
    }
}
```

This will be your "InputLogic" which you can use as `Input.ReadInt("Please specify your age: ");`

Next you can make an `Operations` object :

```
public class Operations
{
    public void Display(int[] arr)
    {
        foreach(int i in arr)
        {
            // and since you have "Input" class that can display things
            Input.Write(i.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Sort(ref int[] arr)
    {
        Array.Sort(arr);
    }
}
```

Now the last thing is to combine it within your `Program`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            int? input = null;
            while( !( input = Input.ReadInt("Give me number") ).HasValue ) { }
            arr[i] = input.Value;
        }

        Operations op = new Operations();
        op.Display(arr);
        op.Sort(ref arr);
        op.Display(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: whoooo I understand this! thank you very muchhhh. . .

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing the parameter for the called function.

```
public static void MethodSort(int[] array)
    {
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}", i);
        }
    }
```

note: not tested

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have two errors, both in this method:

```
public static void MethodSort()
{
    foreach (int i in array)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}", i);
    }
}
```

as well as how you call it:

```
Method.MethodSort(array);
```

The first problem is that the method uses the variable `array`, which doesn't exist in that method's [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

The second problem is that you are passing `array` to the call to `Method.MethodSort`, but that method isn't configured to take a parameter.

There are two ways to approach solving this: remove `array` entirely, or change the method to accept it. Now, you obviously cannot remove `array`, as the whole point is to do stuff with it. Therefore, the logical solution is to add `array` as a parameter to your method:

```
public static void MethodSort(int[] array)
{
    foreach (int i in array)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}", i);
    }
}
```